# Function made of transaction statement on PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgraphile

I want to authenticate an user by its nickname (`networkId`) and before-hand hashed password, with an user public table (`recoyx.user`) and an user private table (`recoyx_private.user`). The function is based on browsing this [PostGraphile tutorial](https://github.com/graphile/postgraphile/blob/v4/examples/forum/TUTORIAL.md#logging-in) (PostGraphile combines GraphQL and PostgreSQL).

```sql
create function recoyx.authenticate(
    network_id text,
    password_hash text
) returns recoyx.jwt_token
begin;
    set local id to (select (numeric_id) from recoyx.user where user.network_id = $1).numeric_id;
    select (numeric_id, password_hash)::recoyx.jwt_token
        from recoyx_private.user
        where user.numeric_id = id and user.password_hash = $2;
end;
```

The query runner is giving invalid syntax within this function overall, both at the part like `select * from recoyx.table where table.field = value`, transaction frames and the `id` binding. I took the query runner from this [example](https://github.com/graphile/cookbook/tree/master/examples/schema_only) which gives a short
facility for initializing, querying and releasing the query runner for the PostgreSQL database (I got here through this [postgraphile module API documentation](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-schema/)).

When I eliminate this function from my query, it runs fine. As far as I've just seen the dot is valid, and the local assignment too. So is my syntax really wrong?

#### Update

Now this is my function:

```sql
create function recoyx.authenticate(
    network_id text,
    password_hash text
) returns recoyx.jwt_token
as
$body$
    select (numeric_id, password_hash)::recoyx.jwt_token
        from recoyx_private.user
        where   numeric_id = (select numeric_id from recoyx.user where network_id = $1)
            and password_hash = $2;
$body$
language sql
stable;
```

I'm getting undefined relations, but I'm connecting to the default root role that comes within my PostgreSQL installation (`postgres` role) as I run the `create function` query

I've put the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/recoyx/sapper-template). I'm running the query through `npm run init-database`. See [environment-example.json](https://github.com/recoyx/sapper-template/blob/master/environment-example.json) (it specifies the conventional "postgres" role).

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) the function body is passed as a string in Postgres (and the tutorial you linked to actually included the necessary `as $$ ...$$` - you just didn't copy it). You also forgot to specify the function's language.

`set local id` is neither a valid variable assignment in [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) nor in SQL (which doesn't have variables to begin with).

But you don't really need a variable to do what you want, your function can be implemented as a SQL function:

```
create function recoyx.authenticate(
    network_id text,
    password_hash text
) returns recoyx.jwt_token
as
$body$
  select (numeric_id, password_hash)::recoyx.jwt_token
  from recoyx_private.user
  where user.numeric_id = (select numeric_id 
                           from recoyx.user 
                           where network_id = $1)
    and user.password_hash = $2;
$body$
language sql
stable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've copied the exact code now. So when the language is `sql`, I get `relation "recoyx_private.user" does not exist` (now I've re-tried it, resulting instead in `syntax error at or near "."` on the where clauses). According to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createfunction.html) I've specified `language plpgsql` (which is valid), and then I now instead get `syntax error at or near "select"` at the outer select.

Comment: If you get "relation does not exist" changing the function's language won't fix that (it would simply defer the error message to a later stage). Apparently you do not have such a table - simple as that (or don't have the privileges, or in a different database, or ...)

Comment: I'm running the query [like this](https://github.com/recoyx/site/blob/master/database/schema/_exec.js#L11) and have environment configuration file [like this](https://github.com/recoyx/site/blob/master/environment-example.json#L4).

Comment: This `create function` is preceded by other queries also... [schema.sql](https://github.com/recoyx/site/blob/master/database/schema/schema.sql). Maybe the role changes once the function body is entered?